beanstalk - docker environment not building but it works locally
I'm trying to build an environment on AWS BEanstalk with this Dockerfile and my Laravel application.
It works fine on my local environment, but on AWS it takes 50 minutes and fails with timeout.
Am I doing something wrong?
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libpng-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install opcache \
    && docker-php-ext-install bcmath \
    && docker-php-ext-install calendar \
    && docker-php-ext-install exif \
    && docker-php-ext-install gettext \
    && docker-php-ext-install pcntl \
    && docker-php-ext-install shmop \
    && docker-php-ext-install sockets \
    && docker-php-ext-install sysvmsg \
    && docker-php-ext-install sysvsem \
    && docker-php-ext-install sysvshm

RUN apt-get install -y nginx

RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" \
    && php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
    && php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY . /var/www/html/

RUN mkdir -p storage/framework/{sessions,views,cache}
RUN mkdir -p bootstrap/cache
RUN chown -R root:root storage
RUN chown -R root:root bootstrap
RUN chmod -R 777 storage
RUN chmod -R 777 bootstrap

RUN composer install

EXPOSE 80

CMD service nginx start && php-fpm && --restart=on-failure


on AWS Elastic Beanstalk can sometimes face issues due to the environment differences or resource constraints.
